# jquery radio button check tick mark should be fired in the div

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gender').change(function(){
    var resultnill="";
    $("#stat5").html(resultnill); 
    var result=$('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    if(result.length>0)
    {
      $("#stat5").append("<img src='tick.png'/>");
    }

  });
 });

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="gender" class="control-label col-xs-4">Gender:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="M" required/>Male</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="F" required/>Female</label>
    </div><div id="stat5"></div>
</div>
```

when i check male radio button tick marks is appearing but if i check female tick box is not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id selector affect only for first element with that id in html document, you can use name selector as following

```
$('input[name=gender]').change(function(){
 //your code
});
```

Comment: it’s my pleasure, you can tick answer

Comment: Friend, i have another question. I have a form with three inputs 1. textbox 2. checkbox 3. dropdownlist. and a submit button. After all the inputs are given then only submit button should be enabled. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify life with a css style declaration:

```
#stat5 {display: none;}
```

Then change your `#stat5` element line to this

```
</div><img id="stat5" src='tick.png'/>
```

Then use jQuery `hide()` and `show()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gender').change(function(){
    var result=$('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    if(result.length>0) 
      $("#stat5").hide();
    else
     $("#stat5").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate id `gender`, alternatively you can user a `class` or `name` on check box as:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="gender" class="control-label col-xs-4">Gender:</label>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="M" required/>Male</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="F" required/>Female</label>
   </div><div id="stat5"></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.gender').change(function(){
   var resultnill="";
   $("#stat5").html(resultnill); 
   var result=$('input[type=radio][name=gender]:checked');   
   if(result.length>0)
   {
     //$("#stat5").append("<img src='tick.png'/>");
   }
 });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/4920/)**